# What's the proper way to associate different account types (database types) to payments and invoices?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, e-commerce, erp, accounting

I've run into a bit of a pickle during my development of a web application.  I've boiled down the complexity of the application for sake of simplicity in this question.

The purpose of this web application is to sell insurance.  Insurance can be purchased through an agent (Agency) or over the phone directly (Customer).  Insurance policies can be paid through the agency or the customer can pay for the policy directly.  So money is owed (invoiced) and received (payments) from multiple sources (Agencies/Customers).

Billing Options:

- Agency (Agency collects from customer outside of app)
- Customer

Here's where it gets complicated.  Agencies are stored in a separate database table than customers (for obvious reasons).  However, both agencies and customers need to be able to make payments and have invoices assigned to them.  I'm having difficulty figuring out how to create the proper database schema to allow for both types of database records to be connected to their invoices and payments.

My initial plan was to set up separate relationship (joining) tables that link the agencies and customers to invoices/payments.
[image: dbschema 01]

However, now that I've been thinking about the problem more, I think it might be beneficial to merge both agencies and customers into a single "Payee" table which would then be associated with payments/invoices.  The payee table would only store a primary key. It would not contain actual names or info for the payee - instead I would pull that data via a JOIN with either the agencies or customers tables.

[image: dbschema 02]

Regardless of whatever solution I choose I am still faced with the problem when creating a new payment record is that I need to scan both the agencies and customers table for possible payees.  I'm wondering if there's a proper way to approach this from a database schema standpoint (or from an accounting/e-commerce standpoint).

What is the correct way to handle this type of situation?  All ideas and possible solutions are most welcome!

**Update 01:**

After a few helpful suggestions (see below) I've come up with a possible solution that may solve this issue while keeping the data normalized.

[image]

The one thing about this method that rubs me the wrong way is that I will have to make multiple table selects to get a list of all the people who can potentially make payments and/or have invoices assigned to them.

Perhaps this is unavoidable though in this situation since indeed there are different "types" of people that can be associated with payments and invoices.  I'm stuck with a situation where I have two different types of records that need to be associated to the same thing.  In the above approach I'm using the FKs to link each table (Agencies/Customers) to a Payee record (the table that unifies both Agencies/Customers) and then ultimately links them to Payments and Invoices.

*Is this the proper solution? Or is there something I've overlooked?*

Comment: When creating a new payment record, what information do you have? Invoice Id? Payee Type? What info do you need to get from those tables to complete the payment?

Comment: @Jk_xp, 99% of the time I'll have the invoiceID, payee type, and either the agencyID or customerID.  1% of the time an administrator will be creating a payment from scratch (manual payment) where they will need to select the payee (either agencyID or customerID) and the corresponding invoiceID (or invoiceIDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

- You might put this like you'd do it with OOP programming and inheritance.

  - There is one table `Person` which holds an uniqueID and a type (Agency, Customer, more in Future). Additionally you might add columns with meta-data like who inserted/when/why and columns for status/soft-delete/???
  - There are two tables Agency and Customer, both holding a `PersonID` as FK.
  - Your `Payee` is the Person
- You might use a schema-bound `VIEW` with a `UNION ALL` to return both tables of your modell in one result. A unique index on this view should ensure, that you'll have a unique key, at least as combination of the table-source and the ID there.
- You might use a middle table with the table-source and the ID *there* as unique Key and use this two-column-id in you payment process
- For sure there are several more...

My best friend was the first option...

Comment: Thank you for listing these options.  Your first option was actually something I considered as well.  Using FK relationships that way I can keep the data better normalized.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be: instead of Payees table - to have two linking tables:

```
PayeeInvoices {
    Id, --PK
    PayeeId, 
    PayeeType, 
    InvoiceId --FK to Invoices tabse
}
```

and

```
PayeePayments {
    Id, --PK
    PayeeId, 
    PayeeType, 
    PaymentId --FK to Payments table.
}.
```

`PayeeType` is an option of two: Customer or Agency. When creating a new payment record you can query `PayeeInvoices` by `InvoiceId` to get `PayeeType` and corresponding `PayeeId`, and then lookup the rest of the data in corresponding  tables.

**EDIT:**

Having second thoughts now. Instead of two extra tables `PayeeInvoices` and `PayeePayments`, you can just have `PayeeId` and `PayeeType` columns right in `Invocies` and `Payments` tables, assuming that Invoice or Payment belongs only to one Payee (Customer or Agency). Both my solutions are not really normalized, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I agree with you that normalization becomes an issue with this type of approach. It's good food for thought.